# Arrays of which size require malloc (or global assignment)?

Tags: c, malloc

While taking my first steps with C, I quickly noticed that int array[*big number*] causes my programs to crash when called inside a function. Not quite as quickly, I discovered that I can prevent this from happening by defining the array with global scope (outside the functions) or using malloc.

My question is:

Starting at which size is it necessary to use one of the above methods to make sure my programs won't crash?

I mean, is it safe to use just, e.g., `int i;` for counters and `int chars[256];` for small arrays or should I just use malloc for **all** local variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should understand what the difference is between `int chars[256]` in a function and using `malloc()`.

In short, the former places the entire array on the stack.  The latter allocates the memory you requested from the heap.  Generally speaking, the heap is much larger than the stack, but the size of each can be adjusted.

Another key difference is that a variable allocated on the stack will technically be gone after you return from the method.  (Oh, your program may function as though it's not gone for a bit if you continue to access that array, but ho ho ho danger lurks.)  A hunk of memory allocated with malloc will remain allocated until you explicitly free it or the program exits.

Comment: Resizing the stack sounds interesting. That would guarantee stability up to a certain (and more important: **known by me**) array size. How can I do that?

Comment: It depends on your compiler/linker. You could Google it.

Comment: I'm new to **compiled** languages, so I didn't realize this was defined by the linker. `-help` gave away the necessary switch.

Comment: Changing the size of the stack is usually only needed when you're doing something like embedded programming on a device where memory is really tight.  You'd probably set the stack size as low as possible in that situation.  I'd say in most cases, you would not INCREASE the stack size just so you could allocate larger arrays as local variables.  You'd probably want to rethink your design in that situation.  (@K-ballo in another comment mentions recursion which might make you consider increasing your stack size, too.)

Comment: Also note that if you declare your array statically within the function (i.e. static int bigarray[1000]), it will be placed on the heap and not the stack. This is not really different than your first working solution (the global variable) other than the scoping.

Comment: @LVB: static int bigarray[1000] will actually end up in the BSS section.

Comment: @Marvo: I'm not trying to force big arrays on the stack. But if I can specify the size, I'll know what will fit and what won't. And yes, it's a recursive sort function.

Comment: @Dennis Be aware that it will declare that array on the stack for EACH INVOCATION of the function.  So if the array is big and you call the function recursively, you're gonna blow the stack fast.  My instinctive starting point would be to use malloc() in that situation.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `malloc` for your dynamic memory allocation. For statically sized arrays (or any other object) within functions, if the memory required is to big you will quickly get a segmentation fault. I don't think a 'safe limit' can be defined, its probably implementation specific and other factors come in play too, like the current stack and objects within it created by callers to the current function. I would be tempted to say that anything below the page size (usually 4kb) should be safe as long as there is no recursion involved, but I do not think there are such guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you have some guarantee that a line will never be longer than 100 ... 1000 characters you can get away with a fixed size buffer. If you don't: you don't. There is a difference between reading in a neat x KB config file and a x GB XML file (with no CR/LF). It depends.

The next choice is: do you want your program to **die gracefully**? It is only a design choice.

Comment: It's not at all about *dying gracefully*. `int array[1000000]` causes my program to crash. `int *array = malloc(4000000)` doesn't...

Comment: @Dennis: it is your program. You are (supposed to be) an engineer. A car is not designed to go 200 KM/h, maybe a computer program is not designed to handle line length of > 200 characters. It is a design choice. OTOH: a computer program can **choose** to die gracefully, a car manufacturer can only say: don't do that.

Comment: We're not understanding each other. I don't want to use malloc to provide a neat error message instead of a simple crash if there's not enough memory available. Neither will be happening if I know beforehand how big the stack is.

Comment: @Dennis: Can only be guaranteed if you know how big the input is. A program that has fixed & limited memory requirements can calculate its memory needs. An XML-processing thingy, or a DBMS, or an editor or browser does not. So it needs a "die-more-or-less-gracefully" strategy.

Comment: @wildplasser: I think the point getting missed is: malloc fails gracefully, by returning 0. The programmer can now do any number of things, including an abrupt exit, but also retrying with smaller request, etc. Allocating a huge array on the stack, causing the stack to overflow (where do you think this site got its name, anyway!?) into the heap, the program itself, or some other invalid place will _crash_ the program. No retry, no user-friendly "That's too big" error message, just, crash. At least on modern OSes, it won't take the whole machine down too.